# HTTP requests between docker containers

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have created two very simple containers to understand/test HTTP requests between containers, but for some reason, I just can't get my containers communicating. I keep getting **GET http://backend:5000/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

My first container, a simple react app with no functionality, just gets container name from `process.env.REACT_APP_URL`, and makes a get request by fetch(`http://${url}:5000/`).

```
import { useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [message, setmessage] = useState("Hello");

  async function buttonClick() {
    let url = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;

    try {
      let response = await fetch(`http://${url}:5000/`);
      console.log("This is response", response);
      setmessage(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error occured:", error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{message}</p>
      <button onClick={buttonClick}>Click Me!</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

My second container, again incredibly simple Flask app, with Hello World served in the homepage route, and nothing else.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return jsonify("Hello World"), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

And their corresponding docker files,

```
FROM node:17.4.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```
FROM python:3.6.5-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add gcc musl-dev libc-dev libc6-compat linux-headers build-base git libffi-dev openssl-dev

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "./myfile.py"]
```

Finally, I am using docker-compose to orchestrate these containers:

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
    container_name: backend
    expose:
      - 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./web
    container_name: frontend
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_URL=backend
    depends_on:
      - "backend"
    links:
      - "backend:backend"
```

My file system is as follows:

```
/sample-app
    |_ server
    |_ web
    |_ docker-compose.yml
```

I have been trying to understand what I am doing wrong and I just can't find it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You haven't provided a runnable example, but I tried to reproduce the error using by using a very simple js app and everything Just Worked. You can see the complete test setup [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-71066611).

Comment: Note that you should remove `link` from your `docker-compose.yml`. That's not the source of your problem, but it's unnecessary and has been deprecated for years. Docker maintains a DNS server that allows containers to look up other containers by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frontend communicates with the backend with the exposed port on the host machine (not a container-container communication that needs to happen if the backend container wanted to connect with a DB container). Therefore, the hostname should be `localhost` not `backend`.

Try with the following change

```yaml
  frontend:
    ...
    ...
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_URL=localhost
    ...
    ...
```

You need to convert the response to JSON as well.

```
      let response = await fetch(`http://${url}:5000/`);
      response = await response.json();
      console.log("This is response", response);
      setmessage(response.data);
```

Comment: @Arty, let me know the result after trying this

Comment: I didn't work. But instead of getting GET http://backend:5000/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, error, I got an empty string response. I think the reason is my frontend container tried to connect to a port 5000 in itself, instead of the backed container.

Comment: your front end container does not communicate with backend its the browser after the frontend is loaded to the browser

Comment: Updated the answer again! Try with that.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much. But this made me wonder another thing. Current docker-compose exposes both of my containers to external access, meaning I can test localhost:5000 via postman with no issue. But I might want to keep my backend private to the external world and make it only accessible within the same docker network. So when I removed port 5000:5000 from the docker-compose, this solution didn't work. Why is that?

Comment: "But I might want to keep my backend private to the external world and make it only accessible within the same docker network. " this is not possible. You can whitelist the frontend domain name in the backend server to avoid access to your backend from others. can you please mark this as the if it solved your issue? Thanks!

Comment: What if I want to connect another flask container to my frontend, for some reason, and this second container is also served in 5000 port. How the front end will know which one to talk to without container names? I was under the impression that this would be done via container names [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20web%E2%80%99s%20application%20code%20could%20connect%20to%20the%20URL%20postgres%3A//db%3A5432%20and%20start%20using%20the%20Postgres%20database.)

Comment: For that you can run a load balancer to devide traffic between two backend containers. https://towardsdatascience.com/sample-load-balancing-solution-with-docker-and-nginx-cf1ffc60e644